# How to set error message if a child is missing in firebase using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app about energy monitoring. In my sign up screen, there are four edit text (fullname, username, email, password) that will be send/ store to the firebase once the registration is successful. The data will be stored by the child username (something like this)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVGoQ.png)

An esp32 is connected to firebase which will store a child under the username called totalEnergy (which is an int not string). (something like this)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2hMt.png)

in the log in screen there are 2 edit text (username, password)

What i would like to do is to set an error which is not letting the user login in the userdashboard if the totalEnergy is not yet stored by the esp32.

basically in order to go to userdashboard, the app need to fetch 5 child (username,fullname,email,password, totalEnergy). if totalEnergy is not yet given , i would like to set an error like "Your account is not yet ready! Please try again later".

Here is the sample code.

```
    public void loginUser(View view) {

    //validate login info
    if (!validateUsername() | !validatePassword()) {
        return;
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isUser();
    }


}

private void isUser() {

    final String userEnteredUsername = username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    final String userEnteredPassword = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = rootNode.getReference("USER INFO");

    Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userEnteredUsername);

    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                username.setError(null);
                username.setErrorEnabled(false);

                String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {

                    username.setError(null);
                    username.setErrorEnabled(false);

                    String fullNameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                    String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);
                    String emailFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDashboard.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                    int totalEnergyFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("totalEnergy").getValue(int.class);

                        intent.putExtra("fullName", fullNameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                        
                        extras.putString("totalEnergy", totalEnergyFromDB + "");
                        intent.putExtras(extras);

                        startActivity(intent);


                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    password.setError("Wrong Password!");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                username.setError("No such user exist!");
                username.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Im been doing this a week now, I cant figure it out! :( Please help !!! THANK YOU!

hello HB. this is the error :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZDeq.png)

hello HB. app error :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVCmg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `esp32` is not `-1` and only continue if it is not, like this:

```java
if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) { 
    username.setError(null);
    username.setErrorEnabled(false); 
    String fullNameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("fullName").getValue(String.class); 
    String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class); 
    String emailFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class); 

    int totalEnergyFromDB = -1;

    try {
        totalEnergyFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("totalEnergy").getValue(int.class);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (totalEnergyFromDB != -1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDashboard.class); 
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        intent.putExtra("fullName", fullNameFromDB); 
        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB); 
        intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB); 
        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB); 
        extras.putString("totalEnergy", totalEnergyFromDB + ""); 
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent); 
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Your account is not yet ready! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the code you sent but it give me error . i will edit my post so you can see the my screenshot.

Comment: for the new user, they dont have esp32 connected to their account thats why totalEnergy is not yet given in the database. they are allow to create account but not allowed to use it because it will be pointless because totalEnergy is not given

Comment: im getting the error message now! wait up i will edit the progressbar !!! YAY!